# Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 will not run a single program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Let me apologize in advance for the new-guy quality of this question.  I would much rather be asking a question about something more interesting, like a challenging [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) question or evolutionary algorithms, but alas I am stuck with major VSE 2012 problems.

Up until around four hours ago, VSE 2012 worked perfectly fine.  Now, I can't even run a simple "Hello, World" program.  No compile errors, although I did have an issue with symbols not being found at the beginning of this nightmare, but I managed to resolve that.  It compiles, but it does not run.  The console window appears, but no output is displayed, no prompt for input is displayed, nothing is processed.  All that appears is the "Please press any key to continue..."

I'm starting to think that my configuration of VSE is corrupted, that maybe I need to uninstall, reboot, and reinstall it all, but I'm hoping that's not the case.  My version of VSE is up to date, as is my redistributable.  My specs are pretty normal, XPS 15z run-of-the-mill laptop running Windows 7, handled VSE perfectly fine for several months until now.

Since VSE started to act up I have been operating through the command line, although I'm really starting to miss an IDE for C++, it just isn't the same.  If VSE doesn't start looking up, I'll just have to get a plug-in for Eclipse or actually put in the time to learn how to use Emacs (maybe this is a sign? haha).

I'm sorry for the rant.  Has anyone experienced problems like this?  The problem isn't that my program is running too quickly (at least I don't think), since prompting for user input doesn't work, nor does the dreaded `system("pause")`.

Any help will be greatly, greatly appreciated.  Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Can you share your code, just to make sure there's nothing obviously wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstall it. If it's compiling and running correctly through the command line then it's a problem with VS.

Considering the issue with the symbols, it sounds like you have the choice of either reinstalling or spending a potential several hours fixing some super specific configuration corruption case.

Comment: I got the solution for the symbols off of another stackoverflow question, so there's no problem there.  Thank you for reassuring me that reinstalling is the right choice.

Comment: After trying an unsuccessful repair and an unsuccessful reinstall, I finally ditched the project I was working on and all associated files I could find (after making backups on a flash drive).  I deleted every VSE temporary file I could find, did one final install with a completely clean slate, and it finally worked.  I noticed a pretty conspicuous difference in the compile process compared to before, I'll try to figure out what exactly the problem was.  Thanks for the help!